# formatar eixo X de barras no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gerei um gráfico de barra no ggplot2 , mas os dados do eixo X não ficaram na sequencia de numero de "1 - 30", gostaria de saber como faço para deixar na sequencia certa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui esta os Script

```
c<-  c ("Casal 1", "Casal 2", "Casal 3", "Casal 4", "Casal 5", "Casal 6", 
                       "Casal 7", "Casal 8", "Casal 9", "Casal 10", "Casal 11", "Casal 12",
                       "Casal 13", "Casal 14", "Casal 15", "Casal 16", "Casal 17", "Casal 18",
                       "Casal 19", "Casal 20", "Casal 21", "Casal 22", "Casal 23", "Casal 24", 
                       "Casal 25", "Casal 26", "Casal 28", "Casal 29", "Casal 30")
r <-  c (1.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3,
0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6,
0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5)

R<- data.frame(c,r)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(R, aes(c,r))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_classic()+theme_light()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = .5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa ordenar a coluna como factor, indicando a ordem requerida.

```
c<-  c ("Casal 1", "Casal 2", "Casal 3", "Casal 4", "Casal 5", "Casal 6", 
        "Casal 7", "Casal 8", "Casal 9", "Casal 10", "Casal 11", "Casal 12",
        "Casal 13", "Casal 14", "Casal 15", "Casal 16", "Casal 17", "Casal 18",
        "Casal 19", "Casal 20", "Casal 21", "Casal 22", "Casal 23", "Casal 24", 
        "Casal 25", "Casal 26", "Casal 28", "Casal 29", "Casal 30")
r <-  c (1.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3,
         0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6,
         0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5)

R<- data.frame(c,r)

### Ordenando coluna c
levels(R$c)
R$c = factor(R$c, levels = c)

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(R, aes(c,r))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_classic()+theme_light()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = .5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]